Applying DB migration to a private Production DB (Azure DB for PostgreSQL)
Firstly, thank you for your time reading this regardless of interaction.
I have a Dev Architecture that I am trying to "Productionise" in a project that I'm doing but struggling to see how CICD can work with a DB that's no accessible via the internet.
Development Env (Background Story)
Firstly, my Dev set up is an Azure App Services and an Azure DB for PostgreSQL both accessible via the internet. I'm using NodeJS with Prisma and have set up a Github Action to Build and Deploy the code to the Azure App Services which also run Prisma Migrate to make the necassery DB Schema changes like so:
  - name: Prisma Migrate Deploy
    run: npx prisma migrate deploy
    env:
      DATABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING }}

Obviously this runs on a GH Server so it's connecting to the DB directly.
Production (Issue I am facing)
So, in short - I want to deploy my code and ensure we carry out the DB migration in the CICD script. However, as the DB is not accessible via the internet and is in a SN inside a Vnet that only Azure App Services can access I am finding it difficult to set up.
How do other projects/organisation cross this hurdle in a safe way? Does anyone have any ideas on how this can be achieved?
Finally, I have tried:

Setting up a VPN Gateway (Super complicated and not cost effective)
Setting up a VM in the VNet to act as the bridge and run the script from there (again costly, but more of a headache to manage and it increase my attach surface)


You have two options.

Deploy a self-hosted actions runner to the database subnet
Configure Azure and GitHub Actions Service to use GitHub-hosted runners.

The simplest is probably option 2. But simple is a subjective term.
Have a read through the following article, which describes how AS communication to private endpoints is facilitated:
About Azure private networking for GitHub-hosted runners in your enterprise
And, at the bottom of that article is a link to the instructions on how to configure Azure and GitHub:
Configuring private networking for GitHub-hosted runners in your enterprise
